# Command `\Gamma' already defined

Tags: packages, incompatibility, font-encodings, classicthesis

I am working on my PhD thesis and I get this error, I have no clue why. I think is a duplicate package but google suggested to use `%\usepackage{fontenc}` but then I got the error "The fontspec package requires either XeTeX or LuaTeX." I am working with texmaker, pdflatex and use make file to compile my document. surprisingly, fontspec package was working for me before with the same build options.

Does anyone have a suggestion for me?

---

```
% ****************************************************************************************************
% 0. Set the encoding of your files. UTF-8 is the only sensible encoding nowadays. If you can't read
% äöüßáéçèê∂åëæƒÏ€ then change the encoding setting in your editor, not the line below. If your editor
% does not support utf8 use another editor!
% ****************************************************************************************************
\PassOptionsToPackage{utf8}{inputenc}
  \usepackage{inputenc}

%\PassOptionsToPackage{T1}{fontenc} % T2A for cyrillics
%  \usepackage{fontenc}


% ****************************************************************************************************
% 1. Configure classicthesis for your needs here, e.g., remove "drafting" below
% in order to deactivate the time-stamp on the pages
% (see ClassicThesis.pdf for more information):
% ****************************************************************************************************
\PassOptionsToPackage{
  drafting=true,    % print version information on the bottom of the pages
  tocaligned=false, % the left column of the toc will be aligned (no indentation)
  dottedtoc=false,  % page numbers in ToC flushed right
  eulerchapternumbers=false, % use AMS Euler for chapter font (otherwise Palatino)
  linedheaders=false,       % chaper headers will have line above and beneath
  floatperchapter=true,     % numbering per chapter for all floats (i.e., Figure 1.1)
  eulermath=false,  % use awesome Euler fonts for mathematical formulae (only with pdfLaTeX)
  beramono=true,    % toggle a nice monospaced font (w/ bold)
  palatino=true,    % deactivate standard font for loading another one, see the last section at the end of this file for suggestions
  style=classicthesis % classicthesis, arsclassica
}{classicthesis}


% ****************************************************************************************************
% 2. Personal data and user ad-hoc commands (insert your own data here)
% ****************************************************************************************************
\newcommand{\myTitle}{A Classic Thesis Style\xspace}
\newcommand{\mySubtitle}{An Homage to The Elements of Typographic Style\xspace}
\newcommand{\myDegree}{Doktor-Ingenieur (Dr.-Ing.)\xspace}
\newcommand{\myName}{André Miede \& Ivo Pletikosić\xspace}
\newcommand{\myProf}{Put name here\xspace}
\newcommand{\myOtherProf}{Put name here\xspace}
\newcommand{\mySupervisor}{Put name here\xspace}
\newcommand{\myFaculty}{Put data here\xspace}
\newcommand{\myDepartment}{Put data here\xspace}
\newcommand{\myUni}{Put data here\xspace}
\newcommand{\myLocation}{Saarbrücken\xspace}
\newcommand{\myTime}{June 2018\xspace}
\newcommand{\myVersion}{\classicthesis}

% ********************************************************************
% Setup, finetuning, and useful commands
% ********************************************************************
\providecommand{\mLyX}{L\kern-.1667em\lower.25em\hbox{Y}\kern-.125emX\@}
\newcommand{\ie}{i.\,e.}
\newcommand{\Ie}{I.\,e.}
\newcommand{\eg}{e.\,g.}
\newcommand{\Eg}{E.\,g.}
% ****************************************************************************************************

% ****************************************************************************************************
% 3. Loading some handy packages
% ****************************************************************************************************
% ********************************************************************
% Packages with options that might require adjustments
% ********************************************************************
\PassOptionsToPackage{ngerman,american}{babel} % change this to your language(s), main language last
% Spanish languages need extra options in order to work with this template
%\PassOptionsToPackage{spanish,es-lcroman}{babel}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{capt-of}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\PassOptionsToPackage{%
  %backend=biber,bibencoding=utf8, %instead of bibtex
  backend=bibtex8,bibencoding=ascii,%
  language=auto,%
  style=numeric-comp,%
  %style=authoryear-comp, % Author 1999, 2010
  %bibstyle=authoryear,dashed=false, % dashed: substitute rep. author with ---
  sorting=nyt, % name, year, title
  maxbibnames=10, % default: 3, et al.
  %backref=true,%
  natbib=true % natbib compatibility mode (\citep and \citet still work)
}{biblatex}
    \usepackage{biblatex}

\PassOptionsToPackage{fleqn}{amsmath}       % math environments and more by the AMS
  \usepackage{amsmath}

% ********************************************************************
% General useful packages
% ********************************************************************
\usepackage{graphicx,psfrag,epsfig,booktabs} %
\usepackage{scrhack} % fix warnings when using KOMA with listings package
\usepackage{xspace} % to get the spacing after macros right
\PassOptionsToPackage{printonlyused,smaller}{acronym}
  \usepackage{acronym} % nice macros for handling all acronyms in the thesis
  %\renewcommand{\bflabel}[1]{{#1}\hfill} % fix the list of acronyms --> no longer working
  %\renewcommand*{\acsfont}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
  %\renewcommand*{\aclabelfont}[1]{\acsfont{#1}}
  %\def\bflabel#1{{#1\hfill}}
  \def\bflabel#1{{\acsfont{#1}\hfill}}
  \def\aclabelfont#1{\acsfont{#1}}
 \usepackage[ruled]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{flexisym}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
```

---

```
%\usepackage{pgfplots} % External TikZ/PGF support (thanks to Andreas Nautsch)
%\usetikzlibrary{external}
%\tikzexternalize[mode=list and make, prefix=ext-tikz/]
% ****************************************************************************************************


% ****************************************************************************************************
% 4. Setup floats: tables, (sub)figures, and captions
% ****************************************************************************************************
\usepackage{tabularx} % better tables
  \setlength{\extrarowheight}{3pt} % increase table row height
\newcommand{\tableheadline}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{l}{\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}}}
\newcommand{\myfloatalign}{\centering} % to be used with each float for alignment
%\usepackage{subfig}
% ****************************************************************************************************


% ****************************************************************************************************
% 5. Setup code listings
% ****************************************************************************************************
\usepackage{listings}
%\lstset{emph={trueIndex,root},emphstyle=\color{BlueViolet}}%\underbar} % for special keywords
\lstset{language=[LaTeX]Tex,%C++,
  morekeywords={PassOptionsToPackage,selectlanguage},
  keywordstyle=\color{RoyalBlue},%\bfseries,
  basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
  %identifierstyle=\color{NavyBlue},
  commentstyle=\color{Green}\ttfamily,
  stringstyle=\rmfamily,
  numbers=none,%left,%
  numberstyle=\scriptsize,%\tiny
  stepnumber=5,
  numbersep=8pt,
  showstringspaces=false,
  breaklines=true,
  %frameround=ftff,
  %frame=single,
  belowcaptionskip=.75\baselineskip
  %frame=L
}
% ****************************************************************************************************




% ****************************************************************************************************
% 6. Last calls before the bar closes
% ****************************************************************************************************
% ********************************************************************
% Her Majesty herself
% ********************************************************************
\usepackage{classicthesis}


% ********************************************************************
% Fine-tune hyperreferences (hyperref should be called last)
% ********************************************************************
\hypersetup{%
  %draft, % hyperref's draft mode, for printing see below
  colorlinks=true, linktocpage=true, pdfstartpage=3, pdfstartview=FitV,%
  % uncomment the following line if you want to have black links (e.g., for printing)
  %colorlinks=false, linktocpage=false, pdfstartpage=3, pdfstartview=FitV, pdfborder={0 0 0},%
  breaklinks=true, pageanchor=true,%
  pdfpagemode=UseNone, %
  % pdfpagemode=UseOutlines,%
  plainpages=false, bookmarksnumbered, bookmarksopen=true, bookmarksopenlevel=1,%
  hypertexnames=true, pdfhighlight=/O,%nesting=true,%frenchlinks,%
  urlcolor=CTurl, linkcolor=CTlink, citecolor=CTcitation, %pagecolor=RoyalBlue,%
  %urlcolor=Black, linkcolor=Black, citecolor=Black, %pagecolor=Black,%
  pdftitle={\myTitle},%
  pdfauthor={\textcopyright\ \myName, \myUni, \myFaculty},%
  pdfsubject={},%
  pdfkeywords={},%
  pdfcreator={pdfLaTeX},%
  pdfproducer={LaTeX with hyperref and classicthesis}%
}


% ********************************************************************
% Setup autoreferences (hyperref and babel)
% ********************************************************************
% There are some issues regarding autorefnames
% https://texfaq.org/FAQ-latexwords
% you have to redefine the macros for the
% language you use, e.g., american, ngerman
% (as chosen when loading babel/AtBeginDocument)
% ********************************************************************
\makeatletter
\@ifpackageloaded{babel}%
  {%
    \addto\extrasamerican{%
      \renewcommand*{\figureautorefname}{Figure}%
      \renewcommand*{\tableautorefname}{Table}%
      \renewcommand*{\partautorefname}{Part}%
      \renewcommand*{\chapterautorefname}{Chapter}%
      \renewcommand*{\sectionautorefname}{Section}%
      \renewcommand*{\subsectionautorefname}{Section}%
      \renewcommand*{\subsubsectionautorefname}{Section}%
    }%
    \addto\extrasngerman{%
      \renewcommand*{\paragraphautorefname}{Absatz}%
      \renewcommand*{\subparagraphautorefname}{Unterabsatz}%
      \renewcommand*{\footnoteautorefname}{Fu\"snote}%
      \renewcommand*{\FancyVerbLineautorefname}{Zeile}%
      \renewcommand*{\theoremautorefname}{Theorem}%
      \renewcommand*{\appendixautorefname}{Anhang}%
      \renewcommand*{\equationautorefname}{Gleichung}%
      \renewcommand*{\itemautorefname}{Punkt}%
    }%
      % Fix to getting autorefs for subfigures right (thanks to Belinda Vogt for changing the definition)
      \providecommand{\subfigureautorefname}{\figureautorefname}%
    }{\relax}
\makeatother


% ********************************************************************
% Development Stuff
% ********************************************************************
\listfiles
%\PassOptionsToPackage{l2tabu,orthodox,abort}{nag}
%  \usepackage{nag}
%\PassOptionsToPackage{warning, all}{onlyamsmath}
%  \usepackage{onlyamsmath}


% ****************************************************************************************************
% 7. Further adjustments (experimental)
% ****************************************************************************************************
% ********************************************************************
% Changing the text area
% ********************************************************************
%\areaset[current]{312pt}{761pt} % 686 (factor 2.2) + 33 head + 42 head \the\footskip
%\setlength{\marginparwidth}{7em}%
%\setlength{\marginparsep}{2em}%

% ********************************************************************
% Using different fonts
% ********************************************************************
%\usepackage[oldstylenums]{kpfonts} % oldstyle notextcomp
% \usepackage[osf]{libertine}
%\usepackage[light,condensed,math]{iwona}
%\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{iwona}
%\usepackage{lmodern} % <-- no osf support :-(
%\usepackage{cfr-lm} %
%\usepackage[urw-garamond]{mathdesign} <-- no osf support :-(
%\usepackage[default,osfigures]{opensans} % scale=0.95
%\usepackage[sfdefault]{FiraSans}
% \usepackage[opticals,mathlf]{MinionPro} % onlytext
% ********************************************************************
%\usepackage[largesc,osf]{newpxtext}
%\linespread{1.05} % a bit more for Palatino
% Used to fix these:
% https://bitbucket.org/amiede/classicthesis/issues/139/italics-in-pallatino-capitals-chapter
% https://bitbucket.org/amiede/classicthesis/issues/45/problema-testatine-su-classicthesis-style
% ********************************************************************
% ****************************************************************************************************
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)  Coud you please make a compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that allows others to reporduce your issue?

Comment: @leandriis How can I upload my thesis? it's a huge file.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Quite likely you have come conflicting packages.  I recommend commenting out unnecessary lines, one by one, and then compiling until you find what is causing the problem. This way you can cut your files down to a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that clearly shows what the problem is. Quite likely at this point you will be able to solve the problem yourself but if not post your MWE (without the commented out lines) and some one is likely to be able to help you.

Comment: Do not upload your complete thesis but try to make a minimal working example. To do so, comment out parts of your document, recompile and see if the error persists. If so, repeat until you have the smallest possible document that still produces the error.

Comment: @leandriis and @Andrew I got the error when I add the `\usepackage{flexisym}`.

Answer (score 5):

Your large code can be reduced to the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{flexisym}
\usepackage{classicthesis}

\begin{document}
text
\end{document}
```

The `flexisym` package is aparently incompatible with the `mathpazo` package that is loaded by `classicthesis` upon compiling with `pdflatex`.

You have the following two options to overcome this:

1. Remove `flexisym` and compile with `pdflatex`
2. Keep `flexisym` and compile with `xelatex` instead.

Comment: That problem solved, but I got this error now ` "\providecommand{\singleletter}[1]{#1}%"' , by any chance you can help me.

Comment: @AH2012: With the information you provided, the error is not reproducible for me. So please make a MWE.

Comment: You could also pass the option `palatino=false` to `classicthesis` and then load the font of your choice, including a newer math package than `mathpazo`. If you also load a package like `unicode-math`, `eulerpx` or `newpxmath`, though, it is unlikely that you also want `flexisym`.

Comment: There is no reason whatsoever for loading `flexisym`. It's loaded automatically by `breqn`, which I discourage using.